# PHP get the available values that they don't exists on the database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the available hours for an appointment website. My mySQL table is looking like this (with examples):

```
id(AI,PK),
date(2016-06-21),
start_time(14:00:00),
end_time(14:30:00),
working(20:00:00),
provider(aaa).
```

I want to echo the available hours between `start_time` and `end_time`. I achieve that with:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `appo` WHERE date = '2016-06-17'";
$result_set = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_set)) {
    for($echodate = 11; $echodate.':00:00' < $row['working']; $echodate++) {
        if($row['start_time'] > $echodate.':00:00' && $row['end_time'] > $echodate.':30:00' || $row['start_time'] < $echodate.':00:00' && $row['end_time'] < $echodate.':30:00') {
            echo $echodate.':00<br>';
            echo $echodate.':15<br>';
            echo $echodate.':30<br>';
            echo $echodate.':45<br>';
        }
    }
    echo '<br>';
    }
}
```

This is working great! But my problem is: if I have two or more registries on the database it echoes back the times on different rows, like this:

Let's say we have two appointments for that day. One at 14:00, ending 14:30 and one at 16:00 ending at 16:30.

My script will echo this:

```
11:00
11:15
11:30
11:45
12:00
12:15
12:30
12:45
13:00
13:15
13:30
13:45
15:00
15:15
15:30
15:45
16:00
16:15
16:30
16:45
17:00
17:15
17:30
17:45
18:00
18:15
18:30
18:45
19:00
19:15
19:30
19:45

11:00
11:15
11:30
11:45
12:00
12:15
12:30
12:45
13:00
13:15
13:30
13:45
14:00
14:15
14:30
14:45
15:00
15:15
15:30
15:45
17:00
17:15
17:30
17:45
18:00
18:15
18:30
18:45
19:00
19:15
19:30
19:45
```

Now, here is the problem. I want to sum them and display only one column. I'm not great with SQL queries. If there is a way (PHP or SQL) to do that I'd be happy to hear it!

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of one of your database entry? How is it saved in the DB?

Comment: id=1
date= 2016-06-17
start_time = 14:00:00
end_time = 14:30:00
working = 20:00:00
provider = aaa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how to handle in database query directly, because you have multiple entries. But you can collect all entries in an array with a loop and then check all entries in another loop, like this way, can't you? Maybe not the fastet way, but a solution.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `appo` WHERE date = '2016-06-17'";
$result_set = mysql_query($sql);

        $working = null;
        $blockedEntries = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_set)) {
                            $working = $row['working'];
                            array_push($blockedEntries, array('start'=>$row['start_time'],'end'=>$row['end_time']));
}

        for($echodate = 11; $echodate.':00:00' < $working; $echodate++) {
            $entryFound = false;
            foreach($blockedEntries as $entry) {
                if(!($entry['start'] > $echodate.':00:00' && $entry['end'] > $echodate.':30:00' || $entry['start'] < $echodate.':00:00' && $entry['end'] < $echodate.':30:00')) {
                            $entryFound = true;
                            break;
                }
            }
            if($entryFound == false) {
                echo $echodate.':00<br>';
                echo $echodate.':15<br>';
                echo $echodate.':30<br>';
                echo $echodate.':45<br>';
            }
        }
```

This code is not tested, but I think, it becomes clear, what I want to achieve.
Can `working` differ in the entries?

Comment: this might work... i can't see why not! i will test it and i will keep you notified!

Comment: array_push return null values the error i'm getting is this:
Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given

Comment: Maybe you need to change `$blockedEntries = [];` to `$blockedEntries = array();`

Comment: did'nt work either. so i managed to get the variables on two different arrays like this:
`$blockedEntries = array('start'=>(array)$row['start_time'],'end'=>(array)$row['end_time']);
$imploded = implode(" ",$blockedEntries['start']);
                            $implodedEnd = implode(" ",$blockedEntries['end']);
                            $test = explode(" ",$imploded);
                            $test2 = explode(" ",$implodedEnd);`

but now it only gets the [0] registry and all other registries ([1],[2],....)
are empty.
Any ideas?

Comment: See my solution again. I did an update. I've tested it now. You just had to remove the `$blockedEntries = ` before the `array_push` function. `array_push` returns an integer value and not a new array. It changes the original array.

Comment: You sir are a genius ! I can't say how thankful i am right now! Thank you so much! Thank you!